# Adding two existing projects of the same name but located in different folders

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have 2 projects that are structured somewhat like:

```
FolderA
   |
   \--> Project1.vcxproj

FolderB
   |
   \--> Project1.vcxproj
```

The two `Project1`s are actually different projects.

When I right-click on my solution and `Add -> Existing Project`, I get the following error.

> The solution already contains an item named 'Project1'.

Given that I can't rename the actual project files and that I want them both added to the same solution, is there any way I could do it?

I've tried many things:

- Renaming the project file in Visual Studio.
- Deleting the .suo file and restarting VS.
- Editing the .sln/.vcxproj files using a text editor (but there was nothing relevant that I could find).

All of the above resulted in the same error.

I would think that since the project files are in separate folders, VS would treat them as separate projects, but there must be something I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you have two project *files* with the same name (not projects with the same name, but project *files*). In your case they are **Project1.vcxproj** and **Project1.vcxproj**. Therefore, you have to rename one of them (and do not forget to rename the corresponding **Project1.vcxproj.filters** file) and only after this add this project to the solution as an existent project.

Maybe the problem can be solved somehow else, without renaming the files, but I do not know how.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing, but I'd rather there was a way without renaming anything...